# How to get rid of the padding area from div?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have a div area like this:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="logo_area" style="background-color:gray;height:40px;">
    <div id="logo" style="float:left;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:80%;height:50%;padding-left:50px;">
    <img border="0" src="images.jpg" width="30" height="30">
    </div>
    <div id="admin" style="padding:15px;">
    <a>LOG IN</a>|<a>SIGN UP</a>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to make the logo_area to become the top of the page (That is, the gray area fill up top of the webpage). But it always has some white padding area around the gray background.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of the white area?

Thanks.

Comment: I created a jsFiddle page with your example,. It seems to be working as you want... http://jsfiddle.net/BN57R/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reset the margin on your `body` tag:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/LDc5p/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin:0;padding:0` to your `id="logo_area"` style. Also add `style="margin:0;padding:0"` to your body tag.
Also note that it is generally better practice to use a separate CSS file than these inline styles.

Comment: Should also do that on your <body> as that's probably a browser default. Look into using a CSS reset style sheet.